# Storing State in Android

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask

I have this listview that gets populated with the data that is downloaded from the internet.
Hence in the onCreate() method, I will run the async task to download the information and put it into the listview.

I placed a boolean value to whether if the list is downloaded or not during the saveInstanceState() method, this will work if the user gets out of the app from the home button and returns. However, when the user exits the program through the back button, the saveInstanceState() method is not run.

I do not want to download the list again, how can I check whether if it's downloaded before?

Answer (score 1):

Check this out: **Implementing the lifecycle callbacks**
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals/activities.html

Use the callbacks to get noticed what happens to your activity and react if nesseceray.

You can use the **Shared Preferences** to store key-value data:
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html

Answer (score 0):

You can override Activity.onBackPressed() and save your state there as well.

Also, you can do

```
void onPause() {
    if(isFinishing()) {
       // save your state. maybe you'd be better off with using preferences (or other things suggested by people here), so you don't need to worry about the instance state.
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you sure that when the application is relaunched, the bundle will be loaded? I'm not sure it would

Comment: Hmm, I'm not sure. I guess you'd have to try it. BTW, I just had another idea for this, which I'm going to put in my answer above.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to persist data beyond the LifeCycle of the application, you'll need to store it outside the Bundle.

Your [options](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html) are:

- [Shared Preferences](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#pref)
- [Internal Storage](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#filesInternal) (on Device)
- [External Storage](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#filesExternal) (memory card)
- [Local Database](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#db)
- [Network](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#netw) (which would probably defeat your question)

I'd suggest a private Internal Storage file for saving your data.